# navigation within interfaces doesn't happen Unhandled Exception: You are trying to use contextless navigation without a GetMaterialApp or Get.key

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

so this is my register code

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Users {
   String name;
   String surname;
   String username;
   String Photo;
   String email;
   String? uid;
   String adress ;


   Users(
       {required this.name,
          required this.email,
           this.uid,
          required this.Photo,
          required this.adress,
       required this.surname,
       required this.username});

 toJson() => {
      "name": name,
      "Photo": Photo,
      "email": email,
      "uid": uid,
      "username": username,
      "surname": surname,
      "adress": adress,
   };
```

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../models/user.dart';

class UserRepository extends GetxController{
  static UserRepository get instance => Get.find();
   final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

   createUser(Users user) async {
     await _db.collection("users").add(user.toJson()).whenComplete(()
          =>  Get.snackbar("Sucess", "Your account has been createdd.",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.1),
            colorText: Colors.green),
     ).catchError((error,stackTrace){
       Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong.Try again",
     snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
     backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.1),
     colorText: Colors.red);
     print(error.toString());
     });
   }
}
```

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/exception/failures.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/screens/signin_screen.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/sidebar/sidebar_layout.dart';

class AuthentificationRepository extends GetxController{
  static AuthentificationRepository get instance=> Get.find();

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late final Rx<User?> firebaseUser;

  @override
  void onReady(){
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 6));
    firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(_auth.currentUser);
    firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());
    ever(firebaseUser, _setInitialScreen);
  }
  _setInitialScreen(User? user){
    user == null ? Get.offAll(()=> SignInScreen()) : Get.offAll(()=>SideBarLayout());
  }

  Future<void> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email , String password) async{
    try{
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      firebaseUser.value != null ? Get.offAll(()=>SideBarLayout()): Get.to(()=>SignInScreen());
    }on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      final ex = SignUpFailures.code(e.code);
      print("FIREBASE AUTH EXCEPTION - ${ex.message}");
      throw ex ;
    } catch(_){
      const ex = SignUpFailures();
      print(" EXCEPTION - ${ex.message}");
      throw ex;
    }
  }
 Future<void> Logout() async=> await _auth.signOut();
}
```

```
    class AuthController extends GetxController {
  static AuthController get instance=>Get.find();

  final password = TextEditingController();
  final email = TextEditingController();
  final username = TextEditingController();
  final adress = TextEditingController();
  final name = TextEditingController();
  final surname = TextEditingController();
  final picture = TextEditingController();

  final userRepo = Get.put(UserRepository());



  void registerUser(String email, String password){
    String? error = AuthentificationRepository().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,  password) as String;
    if(error != null ){
       Get.showSnackbar(GetSnackBar(message: error.toString(),));
    }
  }
  Future<void>createUser(Users user,context)async{
    await userRepo.createUser(user);
    AuthController.instance.registerUser(user.email, password.text.trim());
    Get.to(()=>const SideBarLayout());
  }
}
```

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/screens/reusable_widget.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/repository/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/models/user.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/sidebar/sidebar_layout.dart';
import 'package:movini_mobile/contollers/authController.dart';
class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(AuthController());
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: ExactAssetImage("img/back.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 400,),
              reusableTextField("Enter UserName", Icons.person_outline, false,
                  controller.username),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              reusableTextField("Enter your Name", Icons.lock_outline, false,
                  controller.name),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              reusableTextField("Enter your Surname ", Icons.lock_outline, false,
                  controller.surname),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              reusableTextField("Enter Email Address", Icons.person_outline, false,
                  controller.email),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              reusableTextField("Enter Password", Icons.lock_outline, false,
                  controller.password),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              reusableTextField("Enter your address", Icons.lock_outline, false,
                  controller.adress),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              signInsignUpButton(context, false, () {
                final user = Users(
                    name: controller.name.text.trim(),
                    email:controller.email.text.trim(),
                    Photo:"image.png",
                    adress:controller.adress.text.trim(),
                    surname:controller.surname.text.trim(),
                    username:controller.username.text.trim(),
                );
                AuthController.instance.createUser(user,context);
              })

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

> the thing is the register happens and i found the data in both firebase auth and firebase firestore but the navigation to SideBarLayout (the welcome page) doesn't happens actually nothing happens beside stocking data the button doesnt take anywhere and the exception is EXCEPTION - An unkown error occurred. nd those errors :a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]  for a [GetMaterialApp].

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [flutter document](https://pub.dev/packages/get#counter-app-with-getx), you have to replace `MaterialApp` with `GetMaterialApp` in `main.dart` file.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      //
    );
}
```

Comment: i did and its the same thing the nqvigqtion doesnt happens

Comment: Are you still getting same error?